# Pg_search Multi-search ordering records based on created date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, psql, pg-search

I am implementing PG_search multi-search functionality. i have two modals user and places, i regenerated the documents for both classes and records generated with current date, i want to sort results by users.created date. how can i get results based on specific table record created date?

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 include PgSearch
 multisearchable :against => [:name, :username]
end
class Place < ActiveRecord::Base
 include PgSearch
 multisearchable :against => [:name]
end
```

My Modal have existing records so i reindexed by using following command `PgSearch::Multisearch.rebuild(User)
PgSearch::Multisearch.rebuild(Place)`

I want to get records based on descending order of user and places created date.

Comment: & code you write so far ?

Comment: Put your tried code then answer will be easy & specific

Comment: i updated code:)  when i rebuild multi-search on existing records, all records are created with current date. how to ordering based on user created date